# Index all the intranet with nutch

Tags: nutch, intranet

I use Nutch  and i would like index an intranet, but how to make sure everything on the intranet will be indexed ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you know all the urls of the intranet, then write a robots.txt (or an equivalent page with  all the urls and point the crawler to it).

If you don't then you cannot be never secure that you'll have crawled all the urls, because you cannot verify it after the crawling.

In the last case the best chance is to do the crawl at the maximum depth.

Regards